# How to add content filter into a content page(not in a view)?

Tags: views, nodes

So I'm totally new with the drupal and try to wrap things around my head, which is quite overhelming at first, so my question might be a simple one for pro's.

I'm building Property Listings site where users could submit their own listings, add comments and search and view Property Listings sorted by location, type, price and etc.

So when you search the site on the Search Bar it gives you a page with all the relevant content. For example: If i search for 2bed flats at around 50k they open a page with url defined in taxonomy term"around50k". And now, i have no idea what to do to **add a filter** for "Location" on that page.

I could make the whole new page with a view for that exact type of listings and add whatever filters i want, however as there a hundreds of categories it would be a nightmare.

I know i could add more filters to a search bar, however i will have all Property Type menu on the site and i need **location* and price* filters for each page on that menu.

Is there any functions that would create filters for content on pages or any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Also check out the "learn views" screencasts with Node One: http://nodeone.se/sv/node/661  You may be able to do what you want just by overriding the taxonomy term pages using views alone.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to add the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module.  There's an excellent series of screencasts on [Panels/Page Manager at NodeOne](http://nodeone.se/da/node/682).

Basically, you can use Panels and Page Manager to override paths on your site.  For example, you can override all taxonomy terms.  You can break this down however you like, such as "all taxonomy terms," "all taxonomy terms from a specific category," "one specific taxonomy term," "users with this role on a taxonomy term in this vocabulary," etc.  Then you can create *Variants*, which are page layouts that dictate how the content should be formatted.

Using Panels, you can take the views you make and stick them wherever you like on the site.  It will certainly take some time to learn how to set this up, but learning how views and panels work together will allow you to create very complicated sites with little duplication and certainly no "hundreds of pages" created manually.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, you might just solved one of my biggest headaches! I never looked into the panels module because everyone seems to use views instead..

Comment: Panels was written by the same person who created Views.  Panels extends Views; they are companion modules.  One way of looking at it is that you can stick views into panels.  Why would you want to do that?  Well, the Views module is extremely flexible, but sometimes it doesn't do everything you need.  Panels tries to do that everything else.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to look into the [search_api](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) Module

> This module provides a framework for easily creating searches on any
>   entity known to Drupal, using any kind of search engine. For site
>   administrators, it is a great alternative to other search solutions,
>   since it already incorporates facetting support and the ability to use
>   the Views module for displaying search results, filters, etc. Also,
>   with the Apache Solr integration, a high-performance search engine is
>   available for this module. Developers, on the other hand, will be
>   impressed by the large flexibility and numerous ways of extension the
>   module provides. Hence, the growing number of additional contrib
>   modules (linked below), providing additional functionality or helping
>   users customize some aspects of the search process.

Comment: There is a fair amount of detail in the question about what the poster wants to do.  Simply referring them to the Search API module and posting the introduction from the module's page does not really give any insight into how to solve the problem.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. since he said without views I thought this might of use to him.

Comment: It's fine if you think it's useful, but please explain how the poster might start to implement what he/she wants to do using the module that you suggest.  In some cases, just linking to the module is fine, because simply installing and enabling the module would answer the question.  That is not the case here, though; this is going to be a complicated setup, so it's best to offer a few pointers about how to use the module that you suggest.

Comment: thanks for that tip again. I am on it. let me try to make a small document on that.. :-)

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear, but i didn't mean I want to do this without views. When I use a search bar all the results pages are Just pages with listed content on it. If there's any way to make that Listed content into a view for every part of my vocabulary group that's awesome, however i'm not aware of that.

Comment: with in views you can use filters and then expose the filter that would become a search in itself. I think @PatrickKenny has given you a head start on that. if you need more help do let me know.

Comment: Thanks man, really appreciate the help, been stuck on this for couple of days